# How can I format the value of a Combobox that is displayed in the Textfield after we select a entry

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

Our Problem is, that we have a value type where the Id is a UUID which may not be null. First we tried using `Ext.data.Field` the [defaultValue](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-defaultValue) which seems only to work for null values where the combo retruned a empty string. So we changed the default value of the combo to a empty UUID and turned `forceSelection` on. But now we always start with a empty UUID in the textbox of the combo.

Is there any way to format the value that is diplayed within the texfield of the combobox after we select a record from the list? Or has anyone a better solution to get around the problem to return at least a empty UUID when no value is selected?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say if there is a better way for your UUID problem but you can format the value displayed in the textfield by changing the render template

```
initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;
    me.displayTpl = '<tpl for=".">' +
        '{[(typeof values === "string" ? values : values["' + me.displayField + '"]) === "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ? "" : typeof values === "string" ? values : values["' + me.displayField + '"]]}' +
        '<tpl if="xindex < xcount">' + me.delimiter + '</tpl>' +
    '</tpl>';
    me.callParent(arguments);
}
```